# Opta Planner How could I arrange courses with combined classes

Tags: optaplanner, timetable

I am new to OptaPlanner. I am developing an Time table for a school using optaplanner. 
Optaplanner met most of the requirements 
I would like to have one additional requirement.
The requirement is two courses taught by the the same teacher should be 
given the same periord.

Teacher 1 teaches ENGLISH for curriculum 1 and 2. So whenever ENGLISH is taught in curriculum 1 it has to be assigned in curriculum 2 (same period and room). both curriculum 1 and 2 would share the same room (combined Class)

```
  Period    curriculum 1        curriculum 2           curriculum 3 
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------

  1.P     ENG-teacher1-room1    ENG-teacher1-room1     Math-Another-Teacher-room2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example, one Course.java can have multiple curriculum (it has a curriculumList). So this constraint is already in there.